# Security & Privacy issue: cannot edit options

Tags: macos

I am trying to set password when active the screen saves. This option is in Security & Privacy -> Require Password checkbox.

The problem is that this checkbox is gray - read only access - even if I unlock this in padlock. I am also using the administrator user.

How solve it? Is there any Terminal command to add the password?

I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.3.

Answer (score -2):

Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General:

Select the option "Require password" and set "immediately" on the box with the options.

[image]

Comment: In order to activate the box you have to click on the lock button. It will require your password and you can now make changes.

Comment: I said that it still gray even with this unlock.

Comment: So  your Mac's Shit